# apt-show-versions shows wrong information for custom-made deb package

Tags: debian, apt

When I run `apt-show-versions -a dwm` command([apt-show-versions](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/apt-show-versions) lists available package versions with distribution) then I see following output:

```
# apt-show-versions -a dwm
dwm:i386 6.0-4-martin install ok installed
dwm:i386 6.0-7 jessie http.debian.net
dwm:i386 6.0-4-martin newer than version in archive
#
```

`dwm` was installed with custom-made `deb` package few years ago. However, why does `apt-show-versions` show that it is a newer than the version in the archive when I use `jessie` repos:

```
deb http://http.debian.net/debian jessie main contrib non-free
deb-src http://http.debian.net/debian jessie main contrib non-free
```

..and they should provide `dwm` version [6.0-7](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/dwm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Debian's perspective your private version *is* newer than archive's, but the reason isn't obvious. In Debian versions, the Debian revision [can't contain hyphens](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#s-f-Version), so `6.0-4-martin` is parsed as Debian revision `martin` of upstream version `6.0-4`, whereas `6.0-7` is parsed as Debian revision `7` of upstream version `6.0`. When comparing versions, `6.0-4` is greater than `6.0`...

You can check this using `dpkg --compare-versions`:

```
$ dpkg --compare-versions 6.0-4-martin gt 6.0-7
$ echo $?
0
```

which means `dpkg` considers `6.0-4-martin` as greater than `6.0-7`.

You should use `+` as the separator for private suffixes (`6.0-4+martin` or whatever's appropriate the next time), unless you're preparing a private backport in which case you should use `~`.